# How to combine Retrofit 2 with Realm and RxJava

Tags: multithreading, realm, rx-java, retrofit2

I want to save retrofit responses to realm on the background thread then pass it to the UI Thread, but its a bit tricky since Realm is very touchy with threads. so the code would look like something like this, please submit your edits to all better solutions :)

```
restApi.userRealmList()
        .doOnNext(userRealmModels -> {
            if (userRealmModels != null){
                mRealm = Realm.getInstance(mContext);
                mRealm.asObservable()
                        .map(realm -> mRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(userEntity))
                        .subscribe(new Subscriber<Object>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted() {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onNext(Object o) {
                                Log.d("RealmManager", "user added!");
                            }
                        });
            }})
        .map(userEntityDataMapper::transformAll)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<User>>() {
             @Override
             public void onCompleted() {
                 hideViewLoading();
             }

             @Override
             public void onError(Throwable e) {
                 hideViewLoading();
                 showErrorMessage(new DefaultErrorBundle((Exception) e));
                 showViewRetry();
             }

             @Override
             public void onNext(List<User> users) {
                 showUsersCollectionInView(users);
             }
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You code doesn't look like it can compile? E.g. what is `userEntity`. Also your copyToRealmOrUpdate isn't inside an transaction, so that will also crash, but it has nothing to do with threads.

If you want to save some data as a side-effect before sending it to the UI, you should be able to do the following:

```
restApi.userRealmList()
        .doOnNext(userRealmModels -> {
            if (userRealmModels != null) {
                Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(mContext);
                realm.beginTransaction();
                realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(userRealmModels);
                realm.commitTransaction();
                realm.close();
            }})
        .map(userEntityDataMapper::transformAll)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<User>>() {
             @Override
             public void onCompleted() {
                 hideViewLoading();
             }

             @Override
             public void onError(Throwable e) {
                 hideViewLoading();
                 showErrorMessage(new DefaultErrorBundle((Exception) e));
                 showViewRetry();
             }

             @Override
             public void onNext(List<User> users) {
                 showUsersCollectionInView(users);
             }
        });
```